# a better way of changing the drop down speed

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi i got this little spawn function that drops clouds from the sky.

```
local randomBad1 = function()
    local badC1 = display.newImage("BCloud1.png")
    badC1.x = math.random (0, 450); badC1.y = -50
    physics.addBody( badC1, { density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=45, filter=badc1CollisionFilter } )
    badC1.name = "BCloud1"    
    badC1.isSensor = true
    badC1.rotation = math.random(-20,20) -- Rotate the object
    badC1.gravityScale = 0.40
    local cleanup
    cleanup = function()
       if badC1 then
           if badC1.y >600 then
               badC1:removeSelf()
               badC1 = nil
           end
       end
    end
    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cleanup)
end
randomBadC1 = timer.performWithDelay( 3000, randomBad1, 0 )
```

So i was wondering if there is a better way to change the faling down speed instead of 'gravityScale' ?

Kevin-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `applyForce` to do this to the clouds. I have added some lines to your code as follows:

```
local randomBad1 = function()
  local badC1 = display.newImage("BCloud1.png")
  badC1.x = math.random (0, 450); badC1.y = 50-- -50
  physics.addBody( badC1, { density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=45, filter=badc1CollisionFilter } )
  badC1.name = "BCloud1"    
  badC1.isSensor = true
  badC1.rotation = math.random(-20,20) -- Rotate the object

  -------------------------------------------------------------------
            -- These lines will do it for you --
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  yFor  = math.random(1000)   -- choosing a random y directional Force
  print("yFor = "..yFor)
  badC1:applyForce( 0, yFor, badC1.x, badC1.y )  -- apply the force to your cloud 
  -------------------------------------------------------------------

  badC1.gravityScale = 0.40
  local cleanup
  cleanup = function()
   if badC1 then
       if badC1.y >600 then
           badC1:removeSelf()
           badC1 = nil
       end
   end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", cleanup)
end
randomBadC1 = timer.performWithDelay( 3000, randomBad1, 0 )
```

For more info, you can refer: [Corona Physics Body Properties.](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-physics-bodies)

Keep coding............ :)

Answer (score 0):

If the clouds are the only objects falling, I'd change the gravity completely.

```
physics.setGravity( gx, gy )
```

Comment: i have multiple objects falling and i like to change the speed individually